# Spray io - unable to resolve an error about dependencies in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, spray

I can't try any example from spay.io since I can't resolve an error about dependencies in `build.sbt`. Here is how it looks like:

```
//....skipped

resolvers += "spray repo" at "http://repo.spray.io"

libraryDependencies += "io.spray" % "spray-can" % "1.0"
```

It gives me an error, however:

```
[info] Resolving io.spray#spray-can;1.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: io.spray#spray-can;1.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/alex/.ivy2/local/io.spray/spray-can/1.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/io/spray/spray-can/1.0/spray-can-1.0.pom
[warn] ==== spray repo: tried
[warn]   http://repo.spray.io/io/spray/spray-can/1.0/spray-can-1.0.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/io/spray/spray-can/1.0/spray-can-1.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: io.spray#spray-can;1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#spray-can;1.0: not found
    //..................................... skipped
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: io.spray#spray-can;1.0: not found
```

Even when I change the version to be 1.1, I still have the same error.

What's wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no version `1.0` of spray yet, according to the docs (and browsing the repo): see [spray - Current Versions](http://spray.io/project-info/current-versions/#current-versions).

The latest seems to be either `1.0-M7` for scala 2.9.2 or `1.1-M7` for scala 2.10.0-RC5.

Comment: Exactly, the latest version now is 1.1-M8.